# UITabBarItem image color is grey while original image is white

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I use the following code to create image for my `UITabBarItem`

```
self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_img.png"];
```

This tab_img.png consists of black, white and clear color. But in app all part of image that is black and white turns to grey. How I can change this grey to white ?

[image: this is image that I use]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the image here?

Comment: I've added this home Image.

Answer (score 33):

In iOS7, if you use IB you can subclass UITabBarController then add this:

```
+ (void)initialize
{
    //the color for the text for unselected tabs
    [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]} forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //the color for selected icon
    [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        for (UITabBarItem *tbi in self.tabBar.items) {
            tbi.image = [tbi.image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        }
    }
}
```

if you create the items manualy you must set the UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal on each icon and add the code from initialize.

Comment: The text of the selected item also seems to be affected by the first line. I had to add: [UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]} forState:UIControlStateSelected]; to get the selected item text correct.

Comment: `setSelectedImageTintColor:` is deprecated from iOS8 replace it with `setTintColor:`

Comment: Thanks... just one addition: should also set
tbi.selectedImage = [tbi.selectedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

Comment: Swift version:
`self.tabBar.items?.forEach({ tbi in
                tbi.image = tbi.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal);
                tbi.selectedImage = tbi.selectedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal);
            });`

p.s. I know Swift doesn't need comma but as no newline in comment here, I put commas

Answer (score 16):

If you are using image assets, just set the field "Render As" of your images (selected and unselected images) to "Original Image" ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbxDW.png))

Then in your xib set "Image" and "Selected Image" fields on your Tab Bar Item
([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLR7I.png))

Comment: Thanks, you save my day, also.

Comment: I like this idea but duplicating the image is not the way to go.

Answer (score 10):

Set selected and unselected image.

```
[self.tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mehr_icon"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mehr_icon"]];
```

Comment: The Method is deprecated in iOS 7, Use @Cornel Damian Method in iOS 7 or above.

Comment: that's it, tks @fibnochi

Answer (score 3):

images for UITabBarItems should be alpha channel only !
the opaque part will appear grey (blue if selected) only, though!

take a look at: http://devinsheaven.com/creating-uitabbar-uitoolbar-icons-in-adobe-illustrator/

Comment: Can images for UITabBarItems be white and not grey?

Comment: Not true for iOS 7+. You may use `- imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, I use images with white and alpha only like this [image](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7257444/Haus_weiss.png.html)

I set it with `self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Liste"];`

Comment: changing  [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_img.png"]; to changing  [UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_img"]; doesn't help doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Only Way is to go  to IB(interface builder) and select the   UITabBarItem in your View Controller and go to "file inspector"  scroll down and you will see   Global Tint her you can set it to no color  or any color that you want it will take effect for the selected image.

as per the following code is concern

```
setFinishedSelectedImage: withFinishedUnselectedImage:;
```

this is no longer available in iOS 7 rather we can use

```
[yourCustomTabBarItem setSelectedImage:---];
```

but this will also take effect of this Global tint color.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best way is changing the image color.

```
 func imageWithColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(.normal)

        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage!)

        color.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        newImage.accessibilityIdentifier = accessibilityIdentifier
        return newImage
    }
```

then, you can update the tabBarItem's properties such as image and selectedImage:

```
 func setupColorAttributes(to item: UITabBarItem) {
        item.image = item.image?.imageWithColor(.white)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
        item.selectedImage = item.image?.imageWithColor(.highLight)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    }
```