# Change UITabBar tint colors in the More menu

Tags: ios, uitabbar, tintcolor

I'm trying to change the blue colour from icons in the more menu. I tried almost everything I found on Stack Overflow, but nothing worked.
I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18795117/change-tab-bar-tint-color-ios-7), but is not working.

The only option I found to change the colour was

```
[[UIView appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

but it changes all colours in the app.

[image: tint color not changed]
[image: tint colour changed using UIView appearance tint color]

The code is just a new project with storyboard, so I just added the views on the storyboard.
Thanks for helping.

**Edit:** After I added the code:

```
    UIImage *myImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New Title" image:myImage selectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"]];
```

The image is changed when the view is selected, but it's still blue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what you need, you should use images by creating UITabBarItem for each controller and add an image and a selected image.

See [Apple Documentation about UITabBarItem](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITabBarItem/initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:)

Otherwise looks here, from @Aaron Brager :

- [How to set UITabBarItem's unselected tint, ***including system items*** (iOS7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018242/how-to-set-uitabbaritems-unselected-tint-including-system-items-ios7)
- [UITabBarController unselected icon image tint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036185/uitabbarcontroller-unselected-icon-image-tint)

**Edit after seing the full code**
First there is many mistakes in your project, assets should be in xcassets folder, in view didload write your code after the 'super viewDidLoad]', etc.

About your problem, in your viewDidLoad method in the FirstViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Your code start here, not before the super
    [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    // Get table view of more new viewController
    UITableView *view =(UITableView*)self.tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;

    view.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Change the image color

    if ([[view subviews] count]) {
        for (UITableViewCell *cell in [view visibleCells]) {
            cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]; // Change the text color

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried the code from suggestions but still doesn't work. I guess I'm doing something wrong. I attached the full code if you can take a look.

Comment: @varu I just updated my answer. I didn't understand you were using Storyboard!

Comment: I had this problem with tint color on a bigger project what was begun in 2010 and I had to fix the issue with the icons. I created a new project just for StackOverflow.
Thank you very much for helping me. I really appreciate your help. I still have a lot to learn :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the Swift version of [Ludovic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26106321/3151675).

Keep in mind that this version only changes the tint color, since the original answer did the text color change in a very hacky way. For changing it properly, you'd have to override `moreNavigationController` and its `cellForRowAt` function.

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = .red

if let moreTableView = tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView {
    moreTableView.tintColor = .red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to change color of this button

```
    moreNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
```

[image]

Comment: is there any ways to hide this Edit above button?