# how can I set the tintColor for the tabBar item for the unselected state

Tags: ios, uikit, uitabbar

We can set `UITabBar` item color for the selected state with property `tintColor`, but how can I set the tintColor for the a tab bar item item in  the unselected state?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unselected UITabBar color?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512783/unselected-uitabbar-color)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change tintColor of unselected UITabBarController item title and background image iOS 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551458/change-tintcolor-of-unselected-uitabbarcontroller-item-title-and-background-imag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the tint color for selected and unselected tab bar buttons like this:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

[self calculateFolderSize];
The first line sets the `unselected` color - red in this example - by setting the UIView's `tintColor` when it's contained in a tab bar. Note that this only sets the `unselected` image's tint color - it doesn't change the color of the text below it.

The second line sets the tab bar's selected `image` tint `color` to green.

May be it will help you.

Comment: but in iOS8 the property selectedImageTintColor is deprecated ,and it suggest us to use tintColor to instead,so the first line will set the selected color-red not the unselected,you can test it use a iOS8 sumulator

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105507/change-uitabbar-tint-colors-from-more-menu-in-ios8