# iOS, change the tint of an all white UIImage

Tags: ios, user-interface

I would like to be able to change the color of some of my UI elements, is there a way I can take a white `UIImage` and tint it to any color I want?

Comment: This StackOverflow answer explains how to do that, hope it helps.  [Answer][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19275079/1684508

Comment: possible duplicate of [change image tintColor in ios7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274789/change-image-tintcolor-in-ios7)