# Change only one specific UITabBarItem tint color

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uitabbaritem

It is well known that the tint color of selected (or active) items in a UITabBarController can be easily changed, here is an example:

```
myBarController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In this instance, *any* tab bar item in tabBar will have a red tint once it is made active. Again, this applies to *all* of the items in this tab bar.

How can the active tint color be different between other tab bar items in the same bar? For example, one item might have a red tint while selected, while another might have a blue tint.

I am aware that this can probably be solved by redrawing and subclassing the entire tab bar. However, this is the only change I need, and it seems overkill to do so. I'm not trying to change the style or how the items are rendered in any way, just to make that style different between different items.

I haven't seen any answers to this question anywhere that are relevant to the updates in iOS 7 and 8.

Comment: Please, check my detailed answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002013/different-colors-for-tabbar-items-in-tab-bar-controller/47644313#47644313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some experimenting and based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19275079/353878), found a way to do what I want *without* subclassing UITabBarItem or UITabBar!

Basically, the idea is to create a method of UIImage that mimics the tint mask behavior of UITabBar, while rendering it in its "original" form and avoiding the native tint mask.

All you have to do is create a new instance method of UIImage that returns an image masked with the color we want:

```
@interface UIImage(Overlay)
- (instancetype)tabBarImageWithCustomTint:(UIColor *)tintColor;
@end

@implementation UIImage(Overlay)

- (instancetype)tabBarImageWithCustomTint:(UIColor *)tintColor
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    [tintColor setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    newImage = [newImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    return newImage;
}
@end
```

This is a fairly straightforward version of the code in the answer that I posted, with one exception- the returned image has its rendering mode set to always original, which makes sure that the default UITabBar mask won't be applied. Now, all that is needed is to use this method when editing the tab bar item:

```
navController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" image:normal_image selectedImage:[selected_image tabBarImageWithCustomTint:[UIColor redColor]]];
```

Needless to say, `selected_image` is the normal image one gets from `UIImage imageNamed:` and the `[UIColor redColor` can be replaced with any color one desires.

Answer (score 10):

There is a much easier way to do this!
Add this to the ViewController which UITabBar Item should be in another color

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   // change tint color to red
   [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
   [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```

Insert this to the other ViewControllers

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   // change tint color to black
   [self.tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
   [super viewWillAppear: animated];
}
```

I use this to get different Tint colors in each ViewController
e.g.: [ red | black | green | pink ]

Comment: For anyone using swift: `tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()`

Answer (score 4):

@element119 solution using swift(for you lazy guys):

```
extension UIImage {
    func tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)
        let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)

        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)

        tintColor.setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        newImage = newImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        return newImage
    }
}
```

I'm using this code to tint my middle icon red:

```
if let items = self.tabBar.items as? [UITabBarItem] {
    let button = items[1]
    button.image = button.image?.tabBarImageWithCustomTint(UIColor.redColor())
}
```

Comment: SWIFT 2:  CGBlendMode.Normal instead kCGBlendModeNormal, Thanks for the above answer

Answer (score 3):

This worked fine for me!! code for Swift 3

```
extension UIImage {
    func tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode(rawValue: 1)!)
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:  self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
        tintColor.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)
        var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        newImage = newImage.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        return newImage
    }
}
```

and after...

```
 button.image = button.image?.tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 33.0/255.0, blue: 108.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
```

thanks ;))

Answer (score 0):

swift xcode7.1 tested :

```
extension UIImage {
    func tabBarImageWithCustomTint(tintColor: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)
        let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, CGBlendMode.Normal)
        let rect: CGRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height)

        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)

        tintColor.setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

        var newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        newImage = newImage.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
        return newImage
    }
}
```

fixed the compatibility bug in @Binsh answer

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

```
extension UIImage {
    func tintWithColor(color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
        
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -self.size.height)
        context.setBlendMode(.multiply)
        
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        guard let cgImage = self.cgImage else { return nil }
        context.clip(to: rect, mask: cgImage)
        color.setFill()
        context.fill(rect)
        
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return newImage
        
    }
    
}
```