# How to change a specific bar button item tint color in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tint

I have a `TabBarController` Connected to > `NavigationController` > `TableViewController` and i would like to change the `tintColor` just of a specific page/`barButtonItem` (not all tab bar buttons) .As you know `Runtime Attribute` isn't working anymore in Xcode8.

I have looked across the web and tried different solutions but couldn't make it to work out so please help.

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change only one specific UITabBarItem tint color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918215/change-only-one-specific-uitabbaritem-tint-color)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example written in Swift 3:

```
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "image_path"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTapBarButtonItem))
barButtonItem.tintColor = YOUR_COLOR_HERE
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
```

You place this in the **viewDidLoad** method of your view controller.

Comment: Do i put this in the NavigationController.Swift ( Where the specific button is placed) or in the UITabBarViewController.Swift?

Comment: Edited just now

Comment: Error:`Type 'FavoritesViewController' has no member 'didTapBarButtonItem'`

Comment: You don't have Swift 3 .. And 'didTapBarButtonItem' is a method name I gave as an example ... Try to first learn the language.