# How to change color of UITabBarItem's text

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitabbaritem

I already know how to change the colour of an image of a `UITabBarItem` (from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25062766/887353), but how can I change the colour of its text? I haven't figured it out. Also, how can I change the colour of the image and the text if the `UITabBarItem` is selected? I use Swift with iOS 7 and 8.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor(red: CGFloat(1), green: CGFloat(1), blue: CGFloat(1), alpha: CGFloat(1))], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

For TabBar selected image, you'll need to use `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal` or else the image will have a `blue tint`.

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [[self.tabBar items] objectAtIndex:0];
tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@""] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```