# Change tintColor of Tab Bar in UIView via Storyboard or Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uitabbar

I've [found a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26835148/change-tab-bar-item-selected-color-in-a-storyboard) on how to change the tint color of the tab bar button, but it assumes you are using a tab bar controller. I tried any way and did not make a difference. I am using a regular UIView and dragged a Tab Bar control on there. How do I change the button tint color in this scenario? The storyboard and code suggestions are not making a change. I tried to add these into my `viewDidLoad` ever, but neither had an effect:

```
self.view.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
```

I was able to change the nav bar buttons tints via the storyboard no problem, but the tab bar isn't having any effect. I am trying to match the changes I did to the nav bar:

[image]

Comment: So are you using the TabBarController or not?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using a Tab Bar Controller,** this will work for the tab bar background color:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

And this for the color of the items within the tab bar:

```
tabBarController?.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

**If you are not using a Tab Bar Controller,** and you just dragged a tab bar into your view controller: Control drag from the tab bar in your storyboard to your view controller's swift file to create a new referencing outlet. It should something like this if you're unfamiliar:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTabBar: UITabBar!
```

Then use that same lines of code above just replacing a few things:

```
myTabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
myTabBar.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
```

Comment: This only effects the selected menu item, but what about setting colors for the unselected items?

Comment: For unselected items take a look at this post. You change the color of the tab bar items as opposed to the bar itself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052729/default-tab-bar-item-colors-using-swift-xcode-6