# (Swift) set inactive tab bar image's color?

Tags: ios, image, swift, uicolor, uitabbaritem

I want to know how can I change the color of inactive tab bar's grey shade image. Or if someone can tell me how can I set the image of a tab bar while it's inactive?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Default tab bar item colors using swift Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052729/default-tab-bar-item-colors-using-swift-xcode-6)

Comment: Like that
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

// repeat for every tab, but increment the index each time
UITabBarItem *firstTab = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

// also repeat for every tab
firstTab.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
firstTab.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageSelected.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

Comment: @aBilal17 If you've got an answer, post it as an answer, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

A `UITabBarItem` has `selectedImage` and `image`. You can use a combination of the two to set active/inactive images.

`tabBarController.tabBar.items` will have all the `UITabBarItem`s.

Comment: Like that
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UITabBar *tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar;

// repeat for every tab, but increment the index each time
UITabBarItem *firstTab = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];

// also repeat for every tab
firstTab.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal ];
firstTab.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageSelected.png"]imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];