# Change the text and icon colors for UITabBar and UITabBarItems in XCODE 7 using swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7, ipad-mini

How can I change the text and icon colors for UITabBar and UITabBarItems in XCODE 7 using SWIFT 2? The default gray text seems dim and hard to read for unselected tabbar items.

i want the text and icons white when inactive and this colour: #600c77 (purple) when active.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default tab bar item colors using swift Xcode 6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052729/default-tab-bar-item-colors-using-swift-xcode-6)

Answer (score 2):

For your icon:

```
yourTabBar.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "tab_icon_normal"), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "tab_icon_seelcted"))
```

For your text:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.YOURCOLOR()], forState:.Normal)

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.YOURCOLOR()], forState:.Selected)
```

Comment: how can i get the icons to appear white when inactive and this colour #600c77 when active though

Comment: For that you have to create icon with respective color for selected and deselected respectively