# iOS - TabBar items have different color than assets

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar

The assets I used to build my TabBar have a lighter grey than what I got as a result when running the app on the simulator.

Here is what the app looks like both on simulator and device:
[image]

Here is what the app should look like:

[image]

I am sure I've added the right assets to my project.

Does anyone know why do I have this issue?

Comment: Are you using a tab bar controller?

Comment: If you are using `UITabBarController`, the default color of a `UITabBarItem` is dark gray(the color you see). In order to change the color, you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052729/default-tab-bar-item-colors-using-swift-xcode-6

Comment: Calibrate your monitor?

Comment: @CaptJak, FYI, same issue when testing on device

Comment: @TroyT Yes I am using a tab bar controller

Comment: Well, as @Breek mentioned, you should head over to the linked post to get the desired effect.