# Change color of accessoryType Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6, accessorytype

I'd like to change the color of my cell accessoryType from blue to white.
The textColor is already set to white.
Does someone of you guys know how to do this?

My Code:

`cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark`

Comment: Please don't use force-unwraps. Use `if let`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can set your UITableViewCell tintColor property to the desired color:

```
[cell setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Yes this works. Thanks for your answer! For those who are working with Swift it is: `cell.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()`

Comment: This doesn't work anymore (tested in swift 5)

Answer (score 17):

### Doesn't work for `.disclosureIndicator` ?

If someone is here looking for "How to change color for `.disclosureIndicator` indicator type".

The answer is you **can't**. BUT:

There is a way. Apply a custom image:

```swift
let chevronImageView = UIImageView(image: "disclosureIndicatorImage"))
accessoryView = chevronImageView
```

Additional supporting links:

The image can be downloaded from [here](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=chevron).
How to change color of the image is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26443287/5999975).

Comment: Change the colour of BG & Content view of cell

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .systemGray5
cell.backgroundColor = .systemGray5

Comment: You can use system image named `chevron.right`
 - Usage:
`let accessoryImg = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right")`

Answer (score 15):

Swift:

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Swift 3.0

```
cell.tintColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: Does not work if the accessoryType is .disclosureIndicator

Answer (score 8):

"How to change color for **.disclosureIndicator** indicator type". After much research, I noticed that the image of  disclosureIndicator is not an Image but a backgroundImage. I found a solution like this:

[image]

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


fileprivate func commonInit() {

}

open override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if let indicatorButton = allSubviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UIButton }).last {
        let image = indicatorButton.backgroundImage(for: .normal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        indicatorButton.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
        indicatorButton.tintColor = .red
     }
  }
}

extension UIView {
   var allSubviews: [UIView] {
      return subviews.flatMap { [$0] + $0.allSubviews }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
cell.backgroundColor = .red

Comment: You can add
`extension UITableViewCell {
    func setDisclosureIndicatorColor(_ color: Color) {
        guard let disclosureIndicator = self.allSubviews.compactMap({ $0 as? UIButton }).last else { return }

        let image = disclosureIndicator.backgroundImage(for: .normal)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        disclosureIndicator.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
        disclosureIndicator.tintColor = .soma(color)
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.1:**

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow // the accessoryType background 
cell.tintColor = UIColor.black // the accessoryType tint color.
```

Comment: First of all backgroundColor is color for whole cell (no't only accessory type). Secondly, this solution isn't working anymore. Ive tested it in swift 5.

Comment: @ShadeToD To avoid that inconvenience you can embed a UIView as a container to all your cell elements

Comment: It still won't solve anything as you can't change it via tint property. I think better solution is to use SF Symbols and just insert imageView to accessoryView (by doing that we can se whatever tintColor we want in our imageView)

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5 I am Improving Tung Fam Answer**

```
let chevronImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "chevron-right"))
cell.accessoryView = chevronImageView
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that, I think, is to set accessory to image the following way:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "some image.png")
cell.accessoryView = image
```

Comment: you can't set a UIView to a UIImage

Comment: the good code is this one (you need to use UIImageView instead of UIImage) :

let image = UIImageView(image: "some image.png");
cell.accessoryView = image

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the cell's tint color from the storyboard (assuming you are using a xib file)

Comment: changing cell's tint color did not change that cell's disclosure indicator's color. But i am looking for a way to change accessory color from storyboard

Comment: Changing tintcolor doesnt work for disclosure indicator. A workaround can be as mentioned in  https://medium.com/@ronm333/changing-the-color-of-a-disclosure-indicator-666a7fdd9286

Answer (score 1):

Im my case i need to change contentView color of my CustomCell.

Its can be easy making when u override methods :

```
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {}
```

and:

```
override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {}
```

But when i add to my customCell :

```
cell?.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
```

i had a problem when view under `DisclosureIndicator` is not change color. Its looks like: [image]

So i look on `subviews` of `CustomCell` and find that `DisclosureIndicator` is a button. If change background color of this button u have this [image]

So i try to change background color of `superview` of this button. And its work great.

Full code of `myCustomCell` setHighlighted  func :

```
override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if(highlighted){
        viewContent.view.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.selectedBackground
        for item in self.subviews {
            if ((item as? UIButton) != nil) {
                item.superview?.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.selectedBackground
            }
        }

    } else {
        viewContent.view.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.normalCellBackground
        for item in self.subviews {
            if ((item as? UIButton) != nil) {
                item.superview?.backgroundColor = Constants.Colors.normalCellBackground
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with [this image of yours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaQ9r.png) is that you've only set the `cell.contentView.background` color. You also need to set the `cell.backgroundColor` as well. Then the chevron will have the same background

Answer (score -3):

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = .grey

cell.backgroundColor = .grey