# UITableViewCell editing accessory color

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView and have set multiple selection while editing to true

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

In the cell configuration (cellForRowAtIndexPath), I do:

```
            cell.selectionStyle = .default
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
```

So when tableView is set to editing mode, I get blue checkmark option on the left side. I want to change the default blue color on that accessory. How do I do that?

Comment: see this for help : [Change color of accessoryType Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451482/change-color-of-accessorytype-swift)

Comment: try this `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    cell.tintColor = UIColor.red`

Comment: cell.tintColor is not working for editing checkmark, no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using storyboard :
Change the tint color here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your custom `UITableViewCell`, set `cell's` `tintColor` in `awakeFromNib()` like so,

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.tintColor = .red
    }
}
```

Comment: This works too. But doing it in storyboards is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the cell tint color whatever you want. It will automatically change the accessory type color.

```
[cell setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Comment: Please put this code after set accessory type like below.                                                                
        self.tintColor = UIColor.purple
        self.accessoryType = .checkmark