# Tint is inverting colors in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying out this code to tint color a UIImage but it seems to be inverting the colors - coloring the background and turning the black stroke to white.

How do I have it color the black stroke lines of an image and leave the white background alone?  Here's a playground sample where I try one technique as well as another one suggested by the first answer.

Playground Code

```
 extension UIImage {

    func tint(color: UIColor, blendMode: CGBlendMode = CGBlendMode.Normal) -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
        color.setFill()
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return newImage;
    }

    func tint2(color: UIColor, blendMode: CGBlendMode) -> UIImage
    {
        let drawRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextClipToMask(context, drawRect, CGImage)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(drawRect)
        drawInRect(drawRect, blendMode: blendMode, alpha: 1.0)
        let tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return tintedImage
    }

}

let stringUrl = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/neighbor-chat-assets/icons/avatar1000.png"

let url = NSURL(string: stringUrl)

let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

var originalimage = UIImage(data: data!)

var image = originalimage!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate).tint(UIColor.blueColor(), blendMode:.Normal)
var image2 = originalimage!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate).tint2(UIColor.blueColor(), blendMode:.Normal)
```

Comment: I tried a few including normal and color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I just tested it with a png and transparent background

```
func tint(color: UIColor, blendMode: CGBlendMode = CGBlendMode.Normal) -> UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    color.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274789/how-can-i-change-image-tintcolor-in-ios-and-watchkit) for further information. The alternative would be to wrap your image in a UIImageView with UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate rendering mode, and then set the tintColor property.

**EDIT**

So this is the function you can use to first mask out certain colors if you don't have an alpha channel in an image

```
func tint(color: UIColor, blendMode: CGBlendMode = CGBlendMode.Normal, colorToMask: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()) -> UIImage
{
    var fRed : CGFloat = 0
    var fGreen : CGFloat = 0
    var fBlue : CGFloat = 0
    var fAlpha: CGFloat = 0
    colorToMask.getRed(&fRed, green: &fGreen, blue: &fBlue, alpha: &fAlpha)

    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    var colorMasking : [CGFloat] = [fRed,fRed,fGreen,fGreen,fBlue,fBlue]
    let newImageRef = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors(self.CGImage!, &colorMasking)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, blendMode);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, newImageRef!);
    color.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This function first creates a mask depending on the specified color, and clips the context to this mask.

**EDIT #2**

As stated in the comments, I also didn't manage to mask out the white color, I tried UInt8 values (i.e. 255) and float values (i.e. 1.0), but it still didn't work. So the only solution I could come up with was to invert the image. Here is the function:

```
func negativeImage() -> UIImage {

    let coreImage = MYImage(CGImage: self.CGImage!)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorInvert", withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : coreImage])!
    let result = filter.outputImage!
    let context = CIContext(options:nil)
    let cgimg : CGImageRef = context.createCGImage(result, fromRect: result.extent)

    let bmpcontext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, Int(self.size.width), Int(self.size.height), 8, Int(self.size.width)*4, CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipLast.rawValue)
    CGContextDrawImage(bmpcontext, CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), cgimg)
    let newImgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmpcontext)!
    return UIImage(CGImage: newImgRef)
}
```

You can use it like this

```
var image : UIImage = ...
image = image.negativeImage()
image = image.tint(UIColor.redColor())
```

Here are some general notes

- `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` requires a CGImage with **NO** alpha channel, that's why I use the flag `CGImageAlphaInfo.NoneSkipLast` in the negativeImage function in order to remove the alpha channel again
- There is absolutely no error checking included in this, you should at least check whether there is an alpha channel included within the tint function using `CGImageGetAlphaInfo`
- You can either have the masked out parts (white in our example) transparent (by setting false in the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` command within the tint function), or a specific color by setting true, which is black by default (you would need to paint before clipping to the mask).

Comment: if I wrapped it in an imageview and then pulled the uiimage from it, would it lose the tint?  I need it as an uiimage in the end unfortunately.

Comment: just tried it on this photo http://i300.photobucket.com/albums/nn31/wvufan223/Celtic-Knot-Meanings.png and unfortunately only got a lightly colored background with white lines

Comment: this one seems to invert the image which I don't want, and it doesn't tint the black stroke colors

Comment: That's because you don't have an alpha channel in that image, i.e. the function with color the whole image instead of just the black strokes.

Comment: just tried with the 2nd technique with colorToMask being black - which colors the background and turns the stroke to white.. however using color to mask white just turns the whole image to blue..

Comment: Check the updated answer, I tried masking out the white color but it didn't work, so I created a function to invert the image.