# Swift Can't Change UIImageView image's tint

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have an image icon on storyboard and have been trouble changing it's tint Color. Is there something I'm missing?

```
@IBOutlet weak var tickMarkImage: UIImageView! {
    didSet {
        tickMarkImage.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        tickMarkImage.tintColor = .systemRed
        tickerMarkImage.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing '.systemRed' to 'UIColor.red'?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change image tintColor in iOS and WatchKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274789/how-can-i-change-image-tintcolor-in-ios-and-watchkit)

Comment: Nope, it's still not working.

Comment: Maybe this? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/3327300-withtintcolor

Answer (score 0):

Set the image rendering mode to `.alwaysOriginal`. It worked for me.

This is how I set images (this specific case if for buttons but it's pretty much the same):

```swift
 let imageToSet = UIImage(named: "name")
 button(imageToSet, for: state)
 button = .white
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but it's still not working. I guess the easiest way is to just add the image with tint already added.