# How to set the tint inside of a UIButton using a system icon image?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm setting the image of my UIButton to a system icon

[image]

Is there a way to set the color inside of the button like this?

[image]

Comment: Look at the accepted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274789/how-can-i-change-image-tintcolor-in-ios-and-watchkit

Comment: @Surjeet - that sets the color of the black portion of person.circle.fill, not the actual person inside the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to do this, because the `person.circle.fill` symbol does not support multicolor:

[image: SF Symbols app, inspecting person.circle.fill, but only option is Monochrome]

You could [create a custom symbol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app) and add color there, but this is a lot of work... you'd need to modify each variant.

[image: Custom Symbol Template showing every possible variant of person.circle.fill]

Instead, I would just

1. `Command` + `C` to copy the symbol, in the SF Symbols app
2. Paste it into a vector design app like Sketch
3. Modify the font size there
4. Right-click -> <kbd>Convert to outlines</kbd>
5. Add your color
6. Export as SVG, and drag it into Xcode
7. Set "Appearances" in the Attributes Inspector for the image to <kbd>Single Scale</kbd>

| Steps 1-6 | Step 7 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Setting font size inside Sketch] | [image: Set Appearances to Single Scale] |

Usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("person.circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Red person on black circle image, running on device]