# How to change color for tab bar non selected icon in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

How to change color for tab bar non selected icon and text? I found this answer ([How to change inactive icon/text color on tab bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767098/how-to-change-inactive-icon-text-color-on-tab-bar)), but can't implement it for swift.

Answer (score 42):

iOS 10

```
class TabBarVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // make unselected icons white
        self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Comment: you can put it in AppDelegate , too.

Comment: and how can I use this for iOS 9?

Answer (score 18):

In iOS 11 you can set the property directly at UIToolBar in storyboard:

unselectedItemTintColor | Color | [desired color]

**Xcode print**

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 13):

The below sets the defaults for all UITabBarItem's, you can add it to your `AppDelegate`. It will change your text color.

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes({NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blackColor()}, forState:.Selected)
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes({NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()}, forState:.Normal)
```

For changing the icon' color you can either set the image for the given state where your image already have the good color.

```
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage"]
imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"notSelectedImage"] 
imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Or you can do it this way :

Add an extension to `UIImage` class (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19274789/how-can-i-change-image-tintcolor-in-ios-and-watchkit/24545102#24545102)) :

```
extension UIImage {
func imageWithColor(color1: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() as CGContextRef
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal)

    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height) as CGRect
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
    color1.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() as UIImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
}
```

And in your `viewDidLoad` :

```
for item in self.tabBar.items as [UITabBarItem] {
    if let image = item.image {
        item.image = image.imageWithColor(UIColor.blackColor()).imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4+**

```
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Use this code in `appDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Comment: This is not working for me in Swift 5

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for an iOS 11 swift 4 solution, do something like this in the appDelegate. This is changing all the unselected tab bar items to black.

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementing @BoilingLime's answer, here it goes the second alternative's UIImage extension in Swift 3:

```
extension UIImage {
func imageWithColor(color1: UIColor) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()! as CGContext
    context.translateBy(x: 0, y: self.size.height)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0);
    context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height)
    context.clip(to: rect, mask: self.cgImage!)
    color1.setFill()
    context.fill(rect)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()! as UIImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
}
```