# UITabBar icon previous selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar, uicolor

I'm using custom colors to display in my app,

I need to use three colors:

1. Background - some kind of white
2. Unselected icon - some kind of black
3. Selected icon - purple

Unfortunately, somehow, when I select an Icon and then select another icon, the previous one goes back to the system colouring (circled in red in the attached image).

As part of the colouring I wrote the following code:

```
  //uitabbar background
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor Primary]];

// selected icon tint color
[[UITabBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor Scondary]];

// unselected icon tint color
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor Base]];
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use appearance somewhere else?

Comment: Only for uinavigationbar and statusbar..

Comment: This post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22767226/3222713