# Tab bar with Image & tint color

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to change image on selected `UITabBarButton` or change color of whole tab button(square). Check the reference.

Some apple native app has this type of image & colour,can anyone provide solution?

[image: Tab bar]

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767098/how-to-change-inactive-icon-text-color-on-tab-bar) but it`s little different from what i want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by creating custom view :)