# How to set default tabBarItem selected with tint color?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried `setSelectedItem` in `viewDidLoad`, also tried `selectedIndex` etc.. whatever I found on net.. But I couldn't find any answer. Each item when I am launching the app it shows tab bar in default state not in selected state.
I am also getting error

```
Directly tab bar cannot be modified
```

Comment: Paste some example code, please.

Comment: see this once may be it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767098/how-to-change-inactive-icon-text-color-on-tab-bar

Answer (score 0):

You want to do something like this:

```
UIImage *item2Image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"simulatorTabBarIconUnselected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
        UIImage *item2ImageSelected = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"simulatorTabBarIconSelected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Simulator" image:item2Image selectedImage:item2ImageSelected];
```

Setting the selected image to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate will tint it as your tint color. For the unselected image, apple defaults this to gray no matter what, so the only way around it is to set it to UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal and have the image asset be the color you want it to be. In my case I just made an image asset of the original image but with the alpha at 50% so it looked faded out but still has the same tint.

Comment: I had tried this

 UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Discuss" image:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"u_discuss"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] selectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"discuss_active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];

but still no effect.. help!!

Comment: set the navigation controllers tabBarItem property to the code above. Your tab Bar should contain NavigationControllers, which each contain view controllers

Comment: I am adding this in the view controller itself. Tell me how to add this property

Comment: I had made the function for UITabBarItem in view controller itself

- (UITabBarItem*)tabBarItem {
    UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Discuss" image:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"u_discuss"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] selectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"discuss_active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
    return tabItem;
}

Comment: I only know how to do this the way I described. If you have a tab bar controller, you should make its view controllers all navigation controllers. These navigation controllers will contain each of the view controllers you want to display, and the navigation controller will have the tabBarItem property. The view controller will NOT have the tabBarItem property

Answer (score 0):

```
 let accountBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Account", bundle: nil)
    let accountNav = accountBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() as! CommonNavigationController
    accountNav.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Account", image: UIImage(named: "icon - account")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal), selectedImage: UIImage(named: "icon - account - white")!.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal))
    accountNav.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: STYLES.avenirNextDemiBold11!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState: .Normal)
    accountNav.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()], forState:UIControlState.Selected)
```

You can programmatically change selected-unselected items' color attributes.