# How to set UITabBar unselected ItemTintColor in iOS 9.0

Tags: swift, ios9, uitabbar, tintcolor

How to set **UITabbar** unselected **ItemTintColor** in iOS 9.0 below.
UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor

```
  if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions 
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = .white


    }
```

Comment: Are you serious, who is using iOS 9.0 in today's era?

Comment: No idea! but i need to support this version!  because my app base target is iOS 9.  which iam testing simulator starts from 9 to latest 12 plus.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by assigning two different images for **selected** or **unselected** state.

Or by adding a runtime tint color attribute in storyboard to `UITabBarItem`s:

- for **selected** use `tintColor`
- for **unselected** use `unselectedItemTintColor`

Comment: I did that its working fine from iOS version (10.0) not below like i.e 9.0.  from the above code the selected color showing in white color and unselected colour need to show in red color in below iOS version 9.0

Comment: in that case try using two different images for selected and unselected state
you can refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767098/how-to-change-inactive-icon-text-color-on-tab-bar/29363917