# Change Default "Not Selected" UITabBarItem Image Color

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

how do we change the "Not Selected" or the unhiglighted state of the icons in UITabBarItem?

I tried setting the UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(:) but it only changes the text color.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the default in iOS 7 and above, you have to actually use different icons (in the color you like to have for unselected tabs) and set the color of the text. Instead of creating two sets of icons, you could apply this tweak:

```
// set the selected colors
[self.tabBar setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


UIColor * unselectedColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:184/255.0f green:224/255.0f blue:242/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

// set color of unselected text
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:unselectedColor, NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil]
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

// generate a tinted unselected image based on image passed via the storyboard
for(UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBar.items) {
   // use the UIImage category code for the imageWithColor: method
   item.image = [[item.selectedImage imageWithColor:unselectedColor] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
}
```

[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512783/unselected-uitabbar-color)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using 'xcode' alone. Add two duplicate sets of 'images' to 'Assets.xcassets'. Name the second set of images differently, for example, name them 'yourNameSelected'. Set 'Render As Original Image' property for first (unselected) set of icons:

[image]

Set these images for unselected position:

Set the 'yourNameSelected' duplicate images as Selected Image, then go to the Tab Bar Attributes inspector and select Image Tint you need for the selected tabs color.

If you target is below ios10, you need to import colored images for two states and render both as original image.

Answer (score 0):

In swift tab bar item icons presented by its own image like that, so you can apply your own presets

```
var myImage = UIImage(named: "someImageName")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysTemplate)
myImageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
myImageView.image = myImage
```