# Change UITabBarController Tabs icons color when tab is not selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift2

Good day,
I'm using the UITabBarController from the storyboard, and I want to change the icons colors from the default which is gray to white.
[image]

I tried many solution is found here in stackOverflow, and in other websites but all was useless.

Comment: Can you please provide me link from where you have picked up the example code

Comment: refer this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/790746/how-to-change-uitabbar-selection-color

Comment: when I search again for the links to get the example code I found the solution, thank you all

solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664500/change-default-not-selected-uitabbaritem-image-color

Answer (score 0):

**Default Tab Tint Color:-**

Obj-C Version:-

```
[[self tabBar] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
```

Swift 2.2 Version:-

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
```

**Selected Tab Tint Color:-**

Obj-C Version:-

```
[[self tabBar] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Swift2.2 Version:-

```
self.tabBar.selectedImageTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```

Comment: the code for Default tint color has no effect, and the second code, for the selected tab color, works well, but the function is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution it is was to use this loop

```
for(UITabBarItem *item in self.tabBar.items) {
        // use the UIImage category code for the imageWithColor: method
        item.image = [[[item selectedImage] imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor]] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];


    }
```

in the `UITabBarController` class.
and should add the `UIImage+Overlay` which contains the method `imageWithColor`

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color1
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, self.scale);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage);
    [color1 setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found another solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041127/ios-8-tab-bar-item-background-colour). **It is not necessary to use loop**. I modified his code to remove warnings

> makeImageWithColorAndSize function can be implemented as a normal function

```
extension UIImage {
    func makeImageWithColorAndSize(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Example of use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage().makeImageWithColorAndSize(
              UIColor.blueColor(), 
              size: CGSizeMake(tabBar.frame.width/5, tabBar.frame.height))

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}
```

original code of [Gwendle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051771/gwendle)