# Is it possible to change inactive TabBarIOS Icon color in React Native?

Tags: colors, icons, react-native, native, tabbar

As in subject, I am wondering if right now in React Native is an option to change color of inactive TabBar icon from default gray to custom color? With or without using [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: Why not try and see for yourself ?

Comment: I've tried, but I can't find solution, I tried with styling, with source of icon from react-native-vector-icons with custom color, but it didn't work, gray color was overriding my custom color. So I decided to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, but your icon should be in "inactive" color. To achieve this go to `RTCTabBarItem.m` and change first line in method `setIcon`:

```
- (void)setIcon:(UIImage *)icon
{
  _icon = [icon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
  if (_icon && _systemIcon != NSNotFound) {
    _systemIcon = NSNotFound;
    UITabBarItem *oldItem = _barItem;
    _barItem = [UITabBarItem new];
    _barItem.title = oldItem.title;
    _barItem.imageInsets = oldItem.imageInsets;
    _barItem.selectedImage = oldItem.selectedImage;
    _barItem.badgeValue = oldItem.badgeValue;
  }
  self.barItem.image = _icon;
}
```

Then in all TabBarIOS.Item add field `selectedIcon` with the same url as in `icon` (that's no matter), set `tintColor` of TabBarIOS to "active" color and that's all! TabBar will be rendered with default icon color (inactive), and active icon will be in `tintColor`. I think that TabBar field `renderAsOriginal` should do this, but it not works. After all I found this solution on github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3083

---

Another solution (may not works in some cases):

1. in xCode find file `RCTTabBar.m` (`cmd` + `shift` + `f`)
2. find `- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame`
3. add before `return self`:

```
[[UIView appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UITabBar class], nil] setTintColor: [UIColor redColor]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor: [UIColor greenColor]];
```

4. Restart Simulator/Device

In code `redColor` is color of inactive buttons, and `greenColor` is color of active button. For more details checkout this [Unselected UITabBar color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512783/unselected-uitabbar-color)

Edit: I found great tool if you want convert RGB to UIColor http://uicolor.xyz/